# Gathering category_id value from segment - Low Seg2cat

Tags: categories, segments, low-seg2cat

Not sure if I doing it wrong, my basic url goes like this

====

'site.dev/scooter' - I used {segment_1_category_id} and I get the value of "8" which is correct

If my url is 'site.dev/8' and I used {segment_1_category_name} and I get no results? I tried all the variables on the docs, nothing works.

The docs did not say this extension only works with category_url_title

====

I know I can do it with category loop with {segment_1}, etc etc. If my url goes like this
'site.dev/scooter-unicycle'
My result is 8 and 9 which is correct. This is reason why I am using Low Seg2Cat

====

This is not a duplicate, I have checked other querys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low Seg2Cat only matches on the category_url_title. This is why your first example works and your second example inputting the category ID doesn't.

```
$this->EE->db->select('cat_url_title, '. implode(', ', array_keys($this->fields)))
                         ->from('categories')
                         ->where('site_id', $this->site_id)
                         ->where_in('cat_url_title', $segment_array);
```

I'm not sure on what you're actually trying to do though? If you have a particular problem you need to solve then someone may be able to put forward a suggestion of how to do it with Low Seg2Cat or an alternative solution.

Comment: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/fuzzy-conditionals

Comment: No worries. I've answered over there. :)