# 'Fuzzy' conditionals

Tags: categories, conditionals, segments, advanced-conditionals

feeling little dumb for this.

What I am trying to do is to make my list of checkboxes checked depending on {segment_5}

If the value is '6', that is easy with

```
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{category_id}" {if '{segment_5}' == '{category_id}'}checked='checked'{/if} /> {category_name}
```

I am in a situation where my url goes like this 'site.dev/search/geo/n31lj/6-7' from doing a search. 
Look at {segment_5}, the value is '6-7', multiple categories have been selected.

How can I tell the {category_id} to pick up 6 or 7 inside the {segment_5} with conditionals?

Look at this link, I have tried but it not possible. 
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#comment_box_9433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

== EDIT ==

```
{exp:stash:set name="numbers" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:low_replace find="-" replace="|"}{segment_4}{/exp:low_replace}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:categories channel="items" category_group="3"}
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{category_id}" {exp:loopee foreach="{exp:stash:numbers}" parse="inward"}{if category_id == {loopee_value}}checked='checked'{/if}{/exp:loopee} /> {category_name}<br />
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

This does exactly the job I wanted to do. Converting any segment with values like `5-19-11` into individual values to be checked with a conditional in order to make a checkbox checked

Plugins required 
**Stash 

Low replace 

Loopee**

Comment: Sorry, I can't always post an immediate response as notifications don't come through right away. But the combination between PHP and something like PHPStringFun  as I mentioned was pretty much all you need. Once you split the segment up you can call in those variables as and when you want. This is exactly what I showed in my examples without wrapping it in a foreach loop for the input field (as that wasn't part of the question).

Comment: Thanks Ian for not making me give up ;), the php solution was throwing errors.

Comment: Nicely refined. :) That's an even better way of doing it. Keeping PHP out of templates is always preferable where possible just for extra security.

Answer (score 2):

There are a several ways really. You could use regular PHP:

```
$categories = "{segment_5}"; 

$category = explode("-", $categories);

echo "category 1 = $category[0]"; // 5
echo "Category 2 = $category[1]"; // 6
```

But beware of parse order when integrating with PHP tags.

Alternative you could always have some [string fun](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun). You can take advantage of the full array of PHP string functions such as explode() and split the URL segment by the dash creating an array values (5 and 6 in your case).

```
{exp:phpstringfun function="explode" par1="-" separator="|" reverse="y"}
    {segment_5}
{/exp:phpstringfun}
```

Because segment variables are parsed very early in the rendering of the template this should work fine. I'm exploding segment 5 of the URL by the dash (-) and then replacing it with a pipe (|) character. You could then use that in your query to test for either 5 OR 6 by wrapping that in a [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) variable to call later on in your condtional:

```
{exp:stash:set name="categories" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:phpstringfun function="explode" par1="-" separator="|" reverse="y"}{segment_5}{/exp:phpstringfun} 
{/exp:stash:set}

{if segment_5 == '{exp:stash:categories}'}
    checked='checked'
{/if}
```

That will mark it as checked if `segment_5 == '5|6'`, if that's what you want. Once you have it broken up though you can handle it in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for putting me into a new perspective, this is not really something I want. The segment value is currently '5|6', I need to have a conditional to act like a fuzzy manner, so my conditional should return like this `segment_5 == '5'` OR `segment_5 == '6'` Sorry I should have explained better

Comment: With your code above, that is what I am trying to do.
`{exp:channel:categories channel="items" category_group="3"}
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{category_id}" {if {category_id} == '{exp:stash:categories}' }checked='checked'{/if} /> {category_name} <br /> {/exp:channel:categories}`

'5' works but '6' is ignored

Comment: The PHP way allows you to split them out and retrieve them individually as demonstrated. I just provided a sample of both as I wasn't exactly sure if you wanted an EITHER OR or just individual values. So the segment will always contain either one or two values?

Comment: Sorry, I feel like I am not getting anywhere. The segment will have one or several values. Such as `/5-6` or `/5-9-11` or `/4` (Just making it up). I need to find a way of getting it into an individual value to get a checkbox checked.
`{exp:channel:categories channel="items" category_group="3"} <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{category_id}" {if ??? == ??? }checked='checked'{/if} /> {category_name} <br /> {/exp:channel:categories}`

Comment: To match the category_id

Comment: Sorted, see below. Thank you for putting me into a new perspective, I have poor php knowledge, but not proud for the time I have taken to do this :) When I have more rep points, I will add upmark your answers.

Comment: No problem Dimitri. Providing the pieces of the puzzle and a starting point allows you to explore a little more and apply specifically to your problem. This actually seems like quite a common use case though so I may look to wrap this up into a plugin...